# Can Node.js module caching be used to create globally accessible singletons?

Tags: node.js, dependencies, mongoose

After splitting my project up into many OO classes I am having to pass a reference to my `Model` instance (contains Mongoose models and schema) through multiple constructors.

Would it be bad practice to create an instance of the `Model` class inside the `model.js` module and then require this `model.js` module everywhere I need it?

Something like this:

```
Model = function () { ... }

module.exports = new Model();
```

This would rely on Node's [module caching](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching) to allow the same `Model` instance to be shared between files, like having a global singleton.

Or should I explicitly pass dependencies through constructors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not a bad practice. In fact, many people do it this way.

Comment: Thanks. I realised that I could get my `mongoose` models simply by writing `User = mongoose.model('User')` from any module, so they seem to be using that pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes, this is a bad practice and easily abused. It ensures tightly coupled modules and means that you're going to have to modify every file that touches the database if you ever move away from mongoose. It is bad for all of the same reasons why misusing singletons is bad.

Just because many people do something a particular way in no way indicates that it is a good thing to do.